# How can we schedule a field update for every 6 months?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, scheduled, process-automation, scheduled-flow

I have a formula field Score__c and I have a text field ScoreFrom6MonthsAgo__c.

How could I update a field ScoreFrom6MonthsAgo__c every 6 months with a value from Score__c?

Should I use Schedulable Apex?

Comment: Yes, you can and apart from that maybe you can also opt for Schedule-Triggered Flow also.

Schedule-Triggered Flow: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_trigger_schedule.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

You can use apex scheduler or flow to update field every 6 months.  Below is the sample example.

```
global class Scheduleclass implements Schedulable {
    global void execute (SchedulableContext sdc) {
        List<ABC> ab = [SELECT Id ,ScoreFrom6MonthsAgo__c ,Score__c  FROM ABC];
        for(ABC sc : ab){        
            sc.ScoreFrom6MonthsAgo__c = c.Score__c ;
        }
        update sc;
    }
}
```

To Schedule

```
system.schedule('CRON SET','0 0 1 */6 *',new Scheduleclass());
```

Check details on [Apex scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) along with [example](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/tag/cron-expression/).

Also, you can check details of Scheduling flow [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_start.htm&type=5&release=222) and an example on how to run [Scheduled flows](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/03/03/how-to-schedule-flows-to-run-every-month-year/).

Comment: This is a high-risk code example. It shouldn't be `global`, and it should almost certainly be a Schedulable Batch class to avoid causing limits exceptions, especially given that unbounded query.